# Prove that $\sqrt{1+a} + \sqrt{1+b} + \sqrt{1+c} \leq 4$

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to prove this inequality but I am having some difficulties.

$\sqrt{1+a} + \sqrt{1+b} + \sqrt{1+c} \leq 4$

Edit: sorry i forgot to add a crucial info:
$a + b + c = 2 $ and $a,b,c  \in R+$

Comment: The result is obviously false without some restriction on $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: @user3482749 sorry about that , i forgot to add some info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality): for $x\geqslant-1$ and  $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1$, we have that
$$(1+x)^r \leqslant 1+rx$$

Comment: Great, thank you. Pretty easy after your help.

Comment: @souleatzz I'm glad I could help :) But next time please try to include your work in the question, even if you think that it's wrong :)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. I actually did try it but it was totally wrong and pretty long. Thank you again.